# Django & Jquery : after adding forms with button jquery cannot work correctly

Tags: html, django, formsets

Let's say I have the following formsets.

```
{% for form in formset %}
     <tr style="border:1px solid black;" id="{{ form.prefix }}-row" class="dynamic-form" >

        <td{% if forloop.first %} class="" {% endif %}></td>

            {% render_field form.choicefield1 class="form-control" %}{{form.typeTiers.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% render_field form.choicefield2 class="form-control" %}{{form.tiers1.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.choicefield3 class="form-control"   %}{{form.numfacture1.errors}}
        </td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
  <td><input type="submit" name="ajoutligne" value="Ajouter une ligne" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-row" style="background-color: #8C1944; border-color: #8C1944; float:right;margin: 5px;" onclick="test()"></td></tr>
```

the forms are added using `dynamic-formset.js` , which I call in the code bellow to create a new form when clicking on my button :

```
$(function () {
    $('#add-row').click(function() {

        addForm(this, 'form');
    });       
})
```

and I need to applay jquery function on every row I add in my formset. That's why I created the function `test` called in `onclick`function:

```
var jax= -1;
function test(){
jax =jax+1;
alert($('#id_form-'+jax+'-typeTiers').attr('name'));
$("#id_form-"+jax+"-typeTiers").change(function () {

    alert($('#id_form-'+jax+'-typeTiers').attr('name'));
    x="<option>5</option>";
    y="<option>0</option>";
       $("#id_form-"+jax+"-tiers").html(x);
       $("#id_form-"+jax+"-numfacture").html(y);
      });

      }
```

what I need is to make my rows independent of each other, so if I change the field1 in my first row, only the second field in the same row changes, without affecting the other rows.

**however I have two problems :**

The first : 
when I load the page in the first place, I have the first row showed, but I can't apply the `test()` function on it because `test()` is executed only when clicking on "add" button. So I dont know how to make it work for the first time. in addition to that `test()` is only applied on the first row if the second row is added. same thing : `test()` is only applied on the second row if the tird row is added.

The second : is when I click on `ajoutligne` button more than 1 time, the `x` and `y` variables that should be given to the other two fields in the same row field `$("#id_form-"+jax+"-tiers").html(x);$("#id_form-"+jax+"-numfacture").html(y);`, they are showing on the fields of the row that has the last value of jax.

**For example** : 
if I click on the `ajoutligne`  3 times, so `jax=3`,
and if we are in the `row 0` , this is what should happen when changing `choicefield1`:

`$("#id_form-"+0+"-tiers").html(x);$("#id_form-"+0+"-numfacture").html(y);`

however this happens instead:

```
$("#id_form-"+3+"-tiers").html(x);$("#id_form-"+3+"-numfacture").html(y);
```

I dont know how to solve it. I wish I explained well.

Thank You for Your help.